# Bash script to remove item from Nginx cache

Tags: scripts, nginx

I have Nginx running in Ubuntu. I'm trying to write a script that deletes an item from the Nginx cache.

Script: clear_single_cache_object.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Deleting: " $1
grep -lr $1 /path/to/cache/* | xargs rm
echo "Done"
```

This script is in my home directory and I execute the script in the termial as follows:

```
sh clear_single_cache_object.sh '/images/test.jpg'
```

The output is this:

```
Deleting: /images/test.jpg
: No such file or directory
Done
```

In other words, the script is not working and the item has not been removed from the cache. I have also tried to run the script as root.

If I type the following command in the terminal, then it works fine and the item is removed from the cache.

```
grep -lr '/images/test.jpg' /path/to/cache/* | xargs rm
```

Why does it not work when I run the script? I suspect that it has something to do with the " | xargs rm" part in the script.

Comment: That was a typo. I have made the correction.

Comment: Since the error message appears to be overwriting the filename, I would conclude that the nginx cache uses `\r\n` line endings. Try `grep -lr $1 /path/to/cache/* | od -c` to test my guess.

Comment: Have you tried "%1" instead of %1?

Comment: @glenn jackman - with "od -c" I get the message "d: invalid option --".

Comment: @desgua - yes I have tried that and it didn't work.

Comment: Can you use another solution like: find /path/to/cache/*"$1"* -exec rm {} \;

Comment: @desgua - I updated my script with your suggested command. It didn't work. Then I ran the following command in the termial: find /path/to/cache/*/images/test.jpg* . The result: find: '/path/to/cache/*/images/test.jpg*' : No such file or directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, [glen jackman](https://askubuntu.com/questions/587380/bash-script-to-remove-item-from-nginx-cache#comment814724_587380) was close: your script is using CR-LF (`\r\n`) line endings. For example, I recreated your script with CRLF line endings manually:

```
$ cat foo.sh     
#!/bin/bash
echo "Deleting: " $1
grep -lr $1 foo.txt | xargs echo
echo "Done"
$ file foo.sh 
foo.sh: Bourne-Again shell script, ASCII text executable, with CRLF line terminators
$ sh foo.sh bar
Deleting:  bar
: No such file or directory
Done
```

Change your line endings to the normal form, by installing `dos2unix` and using it to convert:

```
sudo apt-get install dos2unix
dos2unix clear_single_cache_object.sh
```

Second, since you're giving a shebang, why are you calling your script with `sh`? Make it executable and run it drectly:

```
chmod +x clear_single_cache_object.sh
./clear_single_cache_object.sh /images/test.jpg
```

If you'd done that, you could have caught the problem earlier:

```
$ ./foo.sh 
bash: ./foo.sh: bad interpreter: /bin/bash^M: no such file or directory
```

Third, fix your editor. If you're creating the script on Windows and then copying to your server, use a decent editor like Notepad++ which supports Unix line endings (LF).

Comment: It's working now. Thanks for your advice about sh and shebang. I'm new to the world of Linux.